# Error in getting Xml data from GoogleMapsAPI with Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps

**Check this code**

//using the url: [which fetches the xml data find the link here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=chennai&sensor=false)

−

```
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
−
<result>
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
<formatted_address>Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India</formatted_address>
−
<address_component>
<long_name>Chennai</long_name>
<short_name>Chennai</short_name>
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
−
<address_component>
<long_name>Chennai</long_name>
<short_name>Chennai</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
−
<address_component>
<long_name>Tamil Nadu</long_name>
<short_name>TN</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
−
<address_component>
<long_name>India</long_name>
<short_name>IN</short_name>
<type>country</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
−
<geometry>
−
<location>
<lat>13.0604220</lat>
<lng>80.2495830</lng>
</location>
<location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
−
<viewport>
−
<southwest>
<lat>12.9734519</lat>
<lng>80.1215236</lng>
</southwest>
−
<northeast>
<lat>13.1473615</lat>
<lng>80.3776424</lng>
</northeast>
</viewport>
−
<bounds>
−
<southwest>
<lat>12.9459267</lat>
<lng>80.1487827</lng>
</southwest>
−
<northeast>
<lat>13.2340851</lat>
<lng>80.3322913</lng>
</northeast>
</bounds>
</geometry>
</result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

**In this following code ,unable to get the total no of nodes from google map, Can you please fetch the results **

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=chennai&sensor=false",
            dataType: "xml",
            success  : function(xmlData){
            var totalNodes = $('*',xmlData).length; // count XML nodes
            alert("This XML file has " + totalNodes);
            },
            error    : function(){
                 alert("Could not retrieve XML file.");
            }

          });
```

//the output will be This XML file has 20 or more nodes

Comment: In your error: function include the parameters and get the message for a bit more detail about what is exactly going wrong.

Comment: i just want to know the nodes ,, which means the counting of tags inside the xml and responses from tha url

Comment: So it is not erroring then, but always returning `totalNodes` as 0.

Comment: What is actually being returned, and what in that returned data are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this: you are trying to "POST" an ajax request to a domain that you don't own, which is impossible.  You can only submit JSONP requests to external domains.  The only solution you have if you want to use that endpoint is to create a proxy page on your server that will pass your request through to Google and will return the response back to your browser.

There is a native JS solution using methods provided via the Javascript API, which is detailed here: [Google maps geocode API V3 not returning result in javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132685/google-maps-geocode-api-v3-not-returning-result-in-javascript-function)

Answer (score -1):

You aren't passing any API keys to Google Maps which I think you need to do for Google Maps API.

Comment: I am using Gmap V3, so API key is not needed.