# Loading google geocode (from url) data into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geocoding

Google offers a service where you can enter the address, and it will return the latitude and longitude (as well as other information). The way to use this google service is to call a url that returns a JSON. The google URL to call is this: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters` I am trying to make the output of that go into a JSON that I can navigate through and select my desired variables.

Here is my code:

```
address_name = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";
address_name = address_name.replace(/ /gi,'+');

var geocode = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address_name+"&sensor=true";
//alert(geocode)
var json = get_content_from(geocode)
```

I have tried to use .load() but either I'm doing something completely wrong or it just does not work. Is there a way to load this into a variable called json?

Sorry if this is trivial, I have tried searching but I'm not really sure what the keywords would be in this case so I've come up with nothing.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: You could try using jQuery (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132685/google-maps-geocode-api-v3-not-returning-result-in-javascript-function).  Also, you should accept a few more answers :)

Comment: PLEASE use encodeURIComponent, not .replace to put the address in the URL...!

Answer (score 1):

Try this (and make sure you include jQuery).

```
address_name = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";
address_name = address_name.replace(/ /gi,'+');

var geocode = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address_name+"&sensor=true";

$.ajax({
    url:geocode,
    success: function(json){
        console.log(json);
        var data = eval('(' + json + ')');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have already included jquery at the top of the file, will try, thanks. EDIT: and where would I be able to locate the variables after I run this?

Comment: Be sure to look at your JavaScript console to see the output!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no response in the console... I can see that it sent the request, though

Comment: change `console.log(json)` to `alert(json)`.  Any better?  If so, you can assume the JSON was parsed into a JavaScript object and stored in `data`.  Do whatever further processing you need to do right there in the body of that success function.

Comment: thanks, I'll play around with this. appreciate the help edit: no alert when using alert(json), ubt I can still see that there is a request being made, with parameters, no response though