# Function to get Longitude and Latitude from Location using Javascript

Tags: google-maps

My function is like this.

```
function getLatLong(address){
    var latitude="";
    var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        alert(latitude);
});
   return latitude;
}


  alert(getLatLong(co));
```

when i call this function I get empty result but the alert in the function returns the latitude.what the problem?

Comment: the geocode request is asynchronous, so your return statement can execute before the geocode function completes.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Answer (score 0):

I think the ops answer in this question might help :

[Google maps geocode API V3 not returning result in javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132685/google-maps-geocode-api-v3-not-returning-result-in-javascript-function)

As you can see in the solution, the op uses a callback from geocoder.geocode.